# How to save a JSON file after adding/changing new content

Tags: c#, json, csv, json.net

I am currently reading in rows from a csv file and adding them to a JSON.  How do I go about saving the updated JSON file?

Using JSON.net, I am able to append my CSV row (turned JSON object) onto my current json objects, using JObject.AddAfterSelf(jObj).  However, after I open up my Json file again, my new content is no where to be found.  Do I need to call something in order to save my JSON after adding new content to it?

Comment: So you have code that is not working as you expect. If you want help about it probably you should post it. Read about [mcve] and fix your question

Comment: JObject.AddAfterSelf only modifies the object in memory you need to save the object to disk.

Comment: In theory, would I just be taking my entire newly updated json, and call File.WriteToText("myFile.json", output)?  Therefore creating a new json file?

Comment: @theMoreYouNgo Yes.  `File.WriteAllText("myFile.json", jObject.ToString());`

Comment: Thank you all.  @user2927848 This worked just fine.